# For Next loops continues every if at limit

Tags: vb.net, vba, for-loop

I'm working on an application and for some reason I have an issue understanding something. I have code that looks like this....

```
dim number as integer



number = rs.recordcount (only 1 record - so number = 1)
for x = 1 to Number
'stuff
'stuff
    rs.moveNext
Next
```

I'm assuming that once it gets to rs.movenext and then goes onto to Next, it should simply exit the loop - yet it seems to go back to the top of the loop even though there is no record. Anyone have any idea why that's happening?

Comment: Is it because of headers? It might be due to the fact that the header is part of the recordset

Comment: If all you want to do is loop over the records then it's better to use `Do While Not rs.EOF` than to rely on the RecordCount property (which is not always reliable)

Comment: @TimWilliams for some reason I seem to remember only checking `EOF` throwing an error when the recordset has no rows. Am I paranoid to also check for `BOF`?

Comment: I only ever check for EOF: I've never run into a BOF-related issue, but then I pretty much only ever open a recordset and read the records - I don't jump back and forth.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`RecordCount` returns the number of records that have been read, or something like that - *it does not return the total number of records*, that value isn't known until the recordset has been iterated.

So a `For...Next` loop can't iterate a recordset efficiently.

Try a `While` loop instead:

```
While Not rs.BOF And Not rs.EOF
    'stuff
    rs.MoveNext
Wend
```

Comment: Calling `RecordCount` *should* return the total number of records, but it leaves the cursor at the end of the recordset, so if you want to read the records you need to first call `MoveFirst` (and you need to have used the right type of cursor in the first place...)

Comment: Eh, the only recordsets I use are whatever `Command.Execute` returns to me (that's forward-only, isn't it?)

Answer (score 1):

The main reason your loop does not terminate is that you have not given it any conditions that would cause it to terminate.

Also, VB does not check the loop limit each time through the loop.  It only checks it at the beginning.  The following code will still print 100 times even though the value of `Number` changed:

```
Dim Number As Integer = 100
For x As Integer = 0 To Number
    Console.WriteLine(x)
    Number = 99
Next
```

Comment: Thank you, this  is helpful!